# Exporting class vector to .dat in C++

Tags: c++, cryptography

So I'm making a basic cryptocurrency in C++ and I'm trying to export the Blockchain to a .dat file so that the peers can download the blockchain

Blockchain class:

```cpp
#ifndef BLOCKCHAIN_H
#define BLOCKCHAIN_
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>
#include "block.hpp"
class Blockchain
{
    public:
        Blockchain();
        void add_block(Block new_block);
        std::vector<Block> chain;
    private:
        int difficulty;
        Block get_last_block();
};
#endif
```

The blockchain that I want to export is `chain` in this case, so I want to be able to use ofstream to write it to the dat

I tried writing this , but it gave a segmentation fault:

```cpp
#include "blockchain/blockchain.hpp"
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & out, const Block & p) {
    out << p << std::endl;
    return out;
}
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & out, const Blockchain & p) {
    out << p << std::endl;
    return out;
}
int main()
{
    
    Blockchain block_chain = Blockchain();
    std::ofstream outFile("test.dat");

    int i = 0;
    for(; 1 == 1 ;){
        std::cout<<block_chain.chain.size();
        i++;
        std::cout << "Mining block "<<i<<std::endl;
        block_chain.add_block(Block(i, "Block 1 Data"));
        for (const auto &e : block_chain.chain) outFile << e << "\n";
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is there a file format you must use or do you have to define your own? If the answer is "I don't know", start by finding out. We can't do much for you if you don't tell us what the output needs to look like.

Comment: Look carefully at your output operator: it is recursive.

Comment: if by file format you mean ".dat" yes I have to use it

Comment: `.dat` is just a file extension, file extensions are pure convention. A `.dat` file can contain anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here

```
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & out, const Blockchain & p) {
    out << p << std::endl;
    return out;
}
```

I'm not sure what you were expecting but you've written a function which just calls itself. So when you try to output a Blockchain you just get a stack overflow and that's why your program crashes.

What you need to do instead is write `std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & out, const Blockchain & p)` so that it calls a sequence of output operations that output the various parts of a block chain (whatever those are).

Your `Block` operator has the same problem.